# Jquery Dyndatetime datepicker "selected" date bug!

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using http://www.mechanicalmarksy.com/hosted/toolman/dyndatetime/example.html datepicker and everythings works fine, but one bug.

When you select some date for example 20. and go to another (next, previous) month 20. is selected but it shouldn't be.

I can't figure it out how to solve this.

now is February and if you select 20. day it should be selected, but if you move to March or to January 20. shouldn't be selected.

Default example on the link above also functions wrong.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You should contact the author of the control.

Answer (score 1):

try using this alternative datepicker from jQuery UI

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

it doesn't seem to have that bug.

Comment: i know but this has everything i need and is now fully customised only this bug is a problem.

Comment: this is based on http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/old/ which has an updated version without this bug http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/

Answer (score 0):

that's fine, i know about DHTML version, but I have to do it in this jquery version, and only problem is how to remove this selection when is not the current month. Everything else is working just fine...

Comment: you should make comments in the comment area not as an answer. My point above was that the jquery version is based on a dhtml calendar that is broken. the best solution for you i think is to move onto the jquery datapicker as it was designed for jquery from the start and is still supported.